# Trying to add an order_item attribute into the REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, api, sales-order

I'm having trouble trying to add in a custom attribute to the *api/rest/orders* output.

In the checkout we collect a PO Number for each row of items in the basket and save this in the *sales_flat_quote_item* table in the column *itemchsponumber*.

I've tried multiple things to get this value output into the API and although I can get far enough to overwrite each order item xml completely I cannot seem to find a way to extend the order_item xml. (this overwrites the whole order_item row for each product on the order, ideally i'd like to just extend it to show another field)

To overwrite it I changed:

```
$items[$item->getOrderId()][] = $itemsFilter->out($item->toArray());
```

to

```
$items[$item->getOrderId()][] = 'OVERWRITE';
```

but if I try to add any other items into this nothing happens. It seems that the *API/ACL/Resource/Filtering* stuff stops the item being added into the API. I could be caused by system -> web services -> rest attributes but I've checked and my attribute doesn't appear in the list. (this maybe because it's not a product attribute but an order one? :/)

I also have a another field under the table *sales_flat_order_payment* and the column *po_number* but this isn't setup with a custom module so I'm not 100% if this is an attribute or if it's just hacked into the DB/Adminhtml :S

NOTES:
Magento ver. 1.9.1.0
API Type: Rest